# Can I use selenium to get to certain point and after that use request + lxml(or other package like scrapy) to make the process faster?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests, web-crawler

I have a web crawling task which the website needs the user to login and pass the Email 2FA authentication before getting to the main page. On the main page, I have a lot of detail pages(all in the same format) to visit and collect the data and store them in a CSV file.

Now I got no problem with getting to the main page. However, I'd like to optimise tasks after entering the main page, my current solution for this part is I use a for loop and visit each page and collect the data.
for each in page_id_list:
driver.get("https://...." + str(each))
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("...")
....

Functionally it works fine, but I was thinking if I can make the process faster. As selenium loads the whole web page and other packages like request + lxml only retrieve HTML maybe I should somehow use another way to visit those pages, and also I wonder if Scrapy will be useful in my case?

Thank you.

Comment: This may be reaching into the realms of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ rather than a specific coding question. That being said, you can login and render the page with selenium and do data extraction with beautifulsoup that may speed things up. Whatever you do with selenium it's you're always going to comprise on speed thats the downfall of javascript. Another option may be to use requests for the login procedure and checking out the XHR responses for a hidden API instead of using selenium to extract data.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the session cookies/headers generated with Selenium to perform additional requests without Selenium. Handling session expiration and refreshing may not be trivial, though.